# Azure Traffic Manager - Performance Routing - Counter-performing responses times

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

I have an Azure Mobile App backedn with a West Europe endpoint and a Brazil endpoint.
I use Azure Traffic Manager with the routing method set to Performance.
When I test the responses times **from Brazil** (via this [site](https://www.uptrends.com/tools/uptime) for example) I endup with counter performing results:

- testing the Brazil endpoint directly: 0.3s
- testing the West Europe endpoint directly: 2.3s
- testing through Traffic Manager: 2.6s

I also checked (via this [site](https://dnschecker.org/)) that traffic manager was indeed pointing to the Brazil endpoint ip from Brazil and to the West Europe endpoint ip from the rest of the world.

As you can imagine these were not the expected results.

**UPDATE**

Some screenshots.
Here are the results for the TrafficManager endpoint:

[image]

Here are the results for the Brazil endpoint:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I should mention that the exact same tests were returning good and expected results a few weeks ago when I setup Traffic Manager. I re-did these tests because users (rightfully) complained about performance.

Comment: Where is your database that Azure Mobile Apps is connected to?

Comment: db is in West Europe but It's not related to db. I check the root "you app is running page". And calling the brazil endpoint directly is fast.

Comment: ``testing through Traffic Manager: 2.6s`` do you mean that a request sent from Brazil, the response time is 2.6s? or 2.6s is average response time of all requests coming from all around the world.

Comment: The results shown are FROM Brazil.

Comment: I updated the question with screenshots showing results from different cities in the world.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that could be going on here.

1. Traffic Manager has a problem - unlikely, but if all the other thoughts are not working, then this is likely the culprit.
2. The Azure Web Site is cold starting.  The first request to an Azure Web Site causes it to start (unless you have warmed up the site and turned "Always On" on).
3. Something else could be going on with the VM that supports the Azure Web Site.

Try hitting the underlying site a few times.  Ignore the first result.  That should tell you if it's the traffic manager, the web site itself or the cold start problem.

Comment: It's not cold starting, I'm well aware of the issue (and it's not 3s but rather 20s). I should have said that when I've setup traffic manager a few weeks ago I had done the explained tests and results were fine. I didn't change anything on my end since. I just re-did the tests after users complained.

Comment: Note: I tried several times the last 3 days. For example the screenshots were taken this morning while the post was first created yesterday.

Comment: So, it's not the Azure App Service but definitely the Traffic Manager?  Either way, I'd open an Azure Forum post as this has strayed from a technical question into a support issue.